# Odd filename parsing error when scripting emacsclient on OSX

Tags: osx, emacsclient, server, bash

I get the same error as this [Stack Overflow asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116560/open-an-emacs-buffer-when-a-command-tries-to-open-an-editor-in-shell-mode#comment24452_116570) when trying to use a [wrapper script to tell OSX where the emacs server socket is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28553846/2023432):

I don't think it's a bash issue, as the Emacs PID is correctly identified before the error log appears, and `echo $@` returns the appropriate filename:

```
/ » ec installer.failurerequests
installer.failurerequests
Waiting for Emacs...
-emacs-pid 66202
-error Unknown&_command:&_//installer.failurerequests
```

For reference, here is the bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash 

socket_file=$(lsof -c Emacs | grep server | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f8)

if [[ $socket_file == "" ]]; then        

    /Application/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $@ &

else
    ##### THIS IS THE BRANCH THAT IS RUN
    echo "$@"
    emacsclient --socket-name=$socket_file "$@"
fi
```

Is there some extra escaping needed on the emacs server side or something?

Comment: What is the value of `socket_file`?

Comment: @Lindydancer It depends on the session, but in OSX it looks something like this when emacs-server is running: `/var/folders/fq/_rst8fw93jl0dqjsc3vhqzrh0000gn/T/emacs501/server`